# Cannot create indexes for PG in rake migration - Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am trying to write a migration that will create a table and add a couple of indexes.

This is the migration:

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|
        t.string "name", :limit => 50
        t.string "permalink"
        t.integer "position"
        t.boolean "visible"
        t.integer "subject_id"

        add_index("pages","subject_id")
        add_index("pages","name")

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When I trying and run this migration I get the following error:

> PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "pages" does not exist
>   : CREATE  INDEX "index_pages_on_subject_id" ON "pages" ("subject_id")

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Calls to `add_index` are usually outside of the `create_table` block.  Does it work if you move them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the `add_index` method outside your `create_table` block, or call `index` within the block.

The first method:

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|
        t.string "name", :limit => 50
        t.string "permalink"
        t.integer "position"
        t.boolean "visible"
        t.integer "subject_id"

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index("pages","subject_id")
    add_index("pages","name")
  end
end
```

The second method:

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|
        t.string "name", :limit => 50
        t.string "permalink"
        t.integer "position"
        t.boolean "visible"
        t.integer "subject_id"
        t.index("subject_id")
        t.index("name")

      t.timestamps
    end


  end
end
```

Personally I'd go with the second as this is much neater.

Comment: Thanks! I agree that your second solution is neater. However I get 'undefined method 'index' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0x007f877c941b40> when I try t.index('field')